# Window > AVD Manager doesn't exist in my Eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I just install of `Fedora 17`. I'm using `Eclipse 4.2.1`. I have follow a '`My First App`' tutorial. A simple "Hello World" and I can't even get it to run. I have 'Install New Software' a dozen times. It just doesn't show up. No video or tutorial I've seen shows me how to make sure everything is up and functioning correctly and how to fix it if its not. It just says "`install this, click, click, click, then go to Windows > AVD Manager.`" Its not there. This is very frustrating. How can I make an app if I can't even get it to run.

Answer (score 8):

Go to

```
Eclipse->window -> customize Perspective -> Command Groups Availability -> tick the Android SDK and AVD manager.
```

now you can go and see

`Eclipse->window -> AVD Manager`

Answer (score 3):

First of all check that your path to android SDK is correct in

```
Window-> preferences ->Android ->SDK Location.
```

if it is correct then do follow steps to set them to toolbar.

you can view it from here.just do this

```
Eclipse->window -> customize Perspective -> Toolbar Visibility -> tick the Android SDK and AVD manager.
```

you are done.
and if it also doesn't help you anymore then you have to reinstall the SDK.

hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too. After updating to Juno, Android was no where to be found in the preferences nor in File -> New -> Project... nor the Android SDK Manager under Window.

The solution to this was actually that I had an incompatible version of java running, though no error anywhere told me this. After hours of research, I:

- upgraded my JDK to version 7,
- restarted Eclipse,

and everything was working again.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is a little bit late for this answer, but i have had this problem with Mac and after searching and testing a lot of solutions what i had to do is remove my workspace folder.

After that everything has worked as expected.

I hope this will help someone.